# Issue in LinkButton of Gridview using c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to retrieve GridView row data when user will click on edit image of that row.These data should retrieve and set inside some text boxes.I am using onclick event inside link button but unable to fetch row data.My GridView looks like below.

> faq.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-zero" >
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl No">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="faqid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FAQ_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question" >
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="question" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer" >
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="answer" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Answer") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" >
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;" ImageUrl='<%# "/Upload/" + Convert.ToString(Eval("Image")) %>'  /> 
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" >
   <ItemTemplate>
  <!-- <a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="Edit" id="editbtn" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
<a href=" " data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>  -->
    <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="Edit" OnClick="lnkEdit_Click"  ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></asp:LinkButton>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete" CommandName="DoDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FAQ_ID") %>' ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

> Faq.aspx.cs:

```
protected void lnkEdit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;

    TextBox1.Text = grdRow.Cells[1].Text;
    TextBox2.Text = grdRow.Cells[2].Text;
    HiddenField1.Value = grdRow.Cells[0].Text;
    Button1.Text = "Update";
}
```

These Gridview data will set in below textboxes.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="question" accesskey="T"><span class="required">*</span> Question</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  size="30" value="" name="question" ></asp:TextBox>
    <div id="noty" style="display:none;" runat="server"></div>
    <label for="answer" accesskey="A"><span class="required">*</span> Answer</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"  size="30" value="" name="answer" ></asp:TextBox>
    <div id="Div1" style="display:none;" runat="server"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 bannerimagefile">
    <label for="insertimage" accesskey="B"><span class="required">*</span> Insert Image</label>
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="insertimage" id="FileUpload1" onchange="previewFile()" />
    <label for="bannerimage" accesskey="V"><span class="required">*</span> View Image</label>
    <div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
        <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;"   />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" class="submit" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
```

Here i am unable to get the data set in required text boxes.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: specify command argument as CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>" for your link button and retrieve it in gridview's row command event as  int rowIndex = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                GridViewRow row = grdViewName.Rows[rowIndex]

Comment: @ Hakunamatata : Then how can i get the label data ?

Comment: ((Label)row.FindControl("faqid")).Text